# Which data is data.ToList() in Product.cs referring to for the AdventureWorks project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I I have a project - AdventureWorks and a file - Product.cs that contain the code:

```
    public static List<ProductCategory>  GetCategories()
    {
        var db = new AdventureWorksEntities();
        var data = from o in db.ProductCategories orderby o.Name select o;
        return data.ToList();

     }
```

The exception `EntityException was unhandled by user code` was thrown when it hit the following line of code

```
        return data.ToList();
```

So, I use `try` and `catch` to catch the exception and use `Console.WriteLine` to see what is the exception, it will give me

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.EntityException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll
```

and the list box will be empty.

Inside the Default.aspx.cs file, it contain:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            List<ProductCategory> data = DataAccessLayer.Products.GetCategories();

            lbCategories.DataSource = data;
            lbCategories.DataBind();
        }
        else
        {
            if (lbCategories.SelectedIndex != -1)
            {
                string category = lbCategories.SelectedValue;
                Response.Redirect("/Products.aspx?id=" + category);
            }

        }
    }
```

It seems that it will retrieve some form of data / information from the DataAccessLayer.

The following is an extract from the Web.config file:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="AdventureWorksEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/mdlAdventureWorks.csdl|res://*/mdlAdventureWorks.ssdl|res://*/mdlAdventureWorks.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorksLT2008R2;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

The following shows part of the project structure:

```
+ DataAccessLayer
  - Products.cs
+ Styles
  - Site.css
+ Default.aspx
  - Default.aspx.cs
  - Default.aspx.designer.cs
+ mdlAdventureWorks.edmx
  - mdlAdventureWorks.Designer.cs
```

I am suspecting that it might got to do with the mdlAdventureWorks.edmx file but I don't know how can I further troubleshoot and diagnosis the problem since the project was not written by me.

Appreciate any advises given.

Comment: Is your connection string correct to you AdventureWorks database

Comment: I do not know if the connection string is correct but I know that my SQLExpress instance is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this to see if you are actually getting anything back from your database:

```
    public static List<ProductCategory> GetCategories()
    {
        var db = new AdventureWorksEntities();
        try
        {
            if (!db.ProductCategories.Any())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Nothing in DB for ProductCategories");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }

        var data = from o in db.ProductCategories orderby o.Name select o;
        return data.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks sa_ddam213 but now, the exception had hit your line `if (data == null || data.Count() == 0)`

Comment: Thanks sa_ddam213 but now, the exception had hit your line `if (!db.ProductCategories.Any())`

Comment: I have a feeling its not connecting to you database, I have added a try catch to try get a stack trace.